# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createShadowRoot' on 'Element': Shadow root cannot be created on a host which already hosts a shadow tree

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using `webpack 4.29.6` version.

here is the command I am running

```
webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot
```

I am getting two errors in console.

```
 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createShadowRoot' on 'Element': Shadow root cannot be created on a host which already hosts a shadow tree.
at init (chrome-extension://kacljcbejojnapnmiifgckbafkojcncf/include.preload.js:442:39)
at chrome-extension://kacljcbejojnapnmiifgckbafkojcncf/include.preload.js:589:29
bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)



localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at showNeg.js:241
at XMLHttpRequest.onDefaultReadyStateChangeHandler (showNeg.js:311)
```

am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you have any add-blockers installed in your browser please disable them and run the application. you will not get these errors.

Comment: I can confirm - disabling the extension fixed the problem for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Adblock Plus fixed this for me. And then I installed uBlock Origin so that I still have ability to block ads; this extension doesn't interfere with Shadow Dom.